# If $l$ is a derivation and $f$ vanishes in a neighbourhood of $p$, how to show $l(f) = 0$?

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to prove that if $f$ vanishes in a neighborhood of $p$ and $l$ is a derivation then $l(f)=0$. Can someone help me with this issue ?

I was trying to prove that:

$$l(f · g)=0$$

for all $g \neq 0$ but I don't know how to perform that. The other thing was to use the second property of a sheaf of $\mathbb{R}$-algebras to get that

$$l(f(p))=l(1)=0$$

but I think this is not correct.

Thanks a lot in advance.

---

**Definitions**

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf of $\mathbb{R}$-algebras such that $\mathcal{F}(U)$ is a sub-algebra  of continuous functions on $U$ for each $U$ and there exists $f \in \mathcal{F}(U)$ such that $f(p)=1$ and its support is inside $U$ for each $p \in U$.

By a derivation I mean a function

$$l: \mathcal{F}(U) \to \mathbb{R}$$

such that it satisfies the Liebniz rule, this is:

$$l(f·g)=l(f)g(p)+f(p)l(g).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N$ be a neighbourhood of $p$ such that $f|_N = 0$, and let $g$ be a smooth function with $\operatorname{supp}g \subset N$ and $g(p) = 1$. Then, $f\cdot g = 0$ so

$$0 = l(0) = l (f\cdot g) = l(f)g(p) + f(p)l(g) = l(f)1 + 0l(g) = l(f).$$